# calculating rate of return from PV, FV, and monthly contribution

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out what rate of return I would need on an investment in order to compare to paying down a mortgage.

I have calculated the change in the mortgage - I know how much money I'd save by the end of the loan term and how much money I'd need to put in. I'm trying to compare that to an equivalent investment - treat any lump sum payment as the principal of an investment, treat any monthly overpayment as a monthly contribution to an investment, plug in the final value, and solve for the effective rate of return.

I've looked at the `RATE` and the `IRR` commands. `IRR` seems close to what I want, but it wants a series of values for the input flows, but I have it as a periodic regular investment.

For an example with numbers - if I pay an extra $100 a month on the mortgage for 120 months, I can save $10000 in total cost. What command can I use to calculate this in terms of an investment? If I invest $100 a month for ten years and end up with $10000, what was my annualized rate of return?

If I start with principal `PV` invested at rate R,  I contribute monthly payment *M* for *N* months, and I end up with final value `FV` at the end of those N months, I'd like to solve for *R* given the other variables.

I know there's another factor regarding the mortgage interesting being tax deductible - I'll look at worrying about that after I figure this part out.

:)

Comment: Can you post the exact mathematical formulas you want to replicate?

Comment: I tried to add a snippet to make it more clear. I've found lots of formulas which will do this for a loan, where the interest is not compounding and it's coming out of the payment, but I can't figure out how to do it where the interest and payments are both accumulating.

Comment: so, FV = PV(1+r)^N + sum {i=1 to N} of (M*(1+R)^i) , and you want to solve that for R given FV, PV, M and N?

Comment: @vasek1 that looks correct to me. I was hoping this was a common excel formula or something, but I have had trouble finding it. I didn't think it was an uncommon problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your monthly return is given by this `RATE` formula

- number of periods = 120 (10*12)
- contributions of $100 per period
- future value of 10,0000

`=RATE(10*12,-100,0,10000)`
`=-0.32%` per **month**

Note as a check `=RATE(10*12,-100,0,12000)`  = 0

which is equivalent to an annual rate of
`=1-(1-0.32%)^12`
`=-3.73%`

Comment: Thanks, I think I was getting it wrong before because you have to input the PV as negative.